# Video streaming from fragment

Tags: android, video, android-fragments, video-streaming

I'm a new developer and I would like my app to be able to stream videos.
I basically want it to work like YouTube, to be able to stream videos from its own database/server (don't really know how it works yet).
I searched a bit for a way to stream a YouTube video from the media player, and found the code below in few places.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class main_page extends Fragment {
    public main_page() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_page, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        VideoView videoView=(VideoView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vvMainPage);


        MediaController mc=new MediaController(getActivity());
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);

        String str="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvEZUbzqqyM";
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(str);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoView.start();
        videoView.requestFocus();


    }

}
```

I've also added a `VideoView` in the xml file. But it seems to have some kind of problem and I really don't know what is it. The only difference in the code from what I found is that I've modified it to work from a fragment and not from an activity because as for now my app contains only one activity and four three fragments.

So I have 2 questions:
1. Does anyone know whats the problem with my implementation?
2. Is this how I interact with a server ,if I had all my videos on that server - just by writing the url?
Thanks.

Logcat:

```
04-24 18:00:59.956: W/EGL_emulation(1905): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-24 18:01:00.128: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb989d8b8): name, size, mSize = 242, 1048576, 1100992
04-24 18:01:00.352: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98a8d48): name, size, mSize = 244, 100, 1101092
04-24 18:01:00.476: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98957e8): name, size, mSize = 246, 7488, 1108580
04-24 18:01:03.620: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb9899820): name, size, mSize = 255, 7488, 1116068
04-24 18:01:05.500: D/getUser (dev)(1905): First name: dev Last name: dev Email: dev@dev.com Username: dev Password: 123
04-24 18:01:05.616: W/EGL_emulation(1905): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-24 18:01:05.640: D/MediaPlayer(1905): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-24 18:01:05.652: E/MediaPlayer(1905): Unable to to create media player
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905): Unable to open content: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvEZUbzqqyM
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:958)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:946)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:899)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:235)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:51)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:478)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:543)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:671)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1818)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-24 18:01:05.652: W/VideoView(1905):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 18:01:05.656: D/VideoView(1905): Error: 1,0
04-24 18:01:05.808: W/EGL_emulation(1905): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-24 18:01:05.820: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98aea90): name, size, mSize = 263, 19008, 1135076
04-24 18:01:05.832: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98aa748): name, size, mSize = 264, 19008, 1154084
04-24 18:01:05.844: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb989d1d0): name, size, mSize = 265, 4, 1154088
04-24 18:01:07.248: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb98acd60): name, size, mSize = 282, 324, 1154412
04-24 18:01:09.852: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::flush: target size: 692647
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 246, 7488, 1146924
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 255, 7488, 1139436
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 244, 100, 1139336
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 282, 324, 1139012
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 263, 19008, 1120004
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 264, 19008, 1100996
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 265, 4, 1100992
04-24 18:01:09.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1905): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 242, 1048576, 52416
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help???